# How to modify EAR sources on the fly in Wildfly?

Tags: wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 10.  Is there any way to structure my standalone.xml configuration file such that during development, I can deploy an EAR (exploded or not) but have Wildfly point to my static resources directly in my development path?

For instance, if I have an EAR that contains a WAR with the following:

```
EAR
|- EJB module
|- Web module
  \- index.html
  \- js/general.js
  \- *.jsp
  \- WEB-INF
    \- libs
    \- classes
```

I'm looking for a configuration that would allow me to setup my dev machine such that I can modify my *.js, *.html, *.jsp files directly from my development path, and not in the exploded WAR directory.  So basically, I would like to point Wildfly to use all the non-compiled files in my c:\dev\project\web folder instead.

Is this at all feasible?  If not, what is the closest I can get to this?
I've tried updating the undertow subsystem to the following but to no avail:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
            <http-listener name="default" max-parameters="2000" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <location name="/webapp/" handler="web-files"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default" disable-caching-for-secured-pages="false">
            <jsp-config recompile-on-fail="true" modification-test-interval="1" check-interval="1" development="true"/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            <file name="web-files" path="C:/dev/Projects/projectweb/src/main/webapp"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
```

where my application.xml specifies my war as a context path of /webapp.

How else can I structure my development setup to allow modification of my files on the fly?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @SteveC I'm currently using Eclipse.

Comment: It's been a while since I used it, but I believe that the [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org) eclipse plugins will help you with this. These days I use Intellij Idea instead.

Comment: @SteveC The problem with jboss tools plugin is that the build isn't able to run cleanly in eclipse due to some unsupported maven plugins. So I end up having to run maven by hand at command line and deploying and ear each time. Gets fairly tiring. So am looking for a way to configure wildly deployment descriptors to point to my static files directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss Tools, Idea or NetBeans allows you do to that automatically for 'static' content, for classes it would do it also but it will trigger a redeployments to be 'sure' that the new classes are taken into account.

Comment: The problem with jboss tools plugin is that the build isn't able to run cleanly in eclipse due to some unsupported maven plugins.  So I end up having to run maven by hand at command line and deploying and ear each time.  Gets fairly tiring.  So am looking for a way to configure wildly deployment descriptors to point to my static files directly instead.

Comment: One solution would be to script the replacement of your static content using jboss-cli and exploded managed deployments

Comment: that is essentially what i ended up doing but was hoping there would be a more elegant method.  Thanks